# Induction motor wiring

Tags: induction-motor

I took this motor out of a drier and want to run it.

**It has 3 wires:**

> Yellow: connected to the capacitor
>   Brown: connected to the capacitor other end
>   Black: not connected to anything.

Capacitor is 8 uF

**I measured:**

> Yellow to black measures 40 ohms
>   Brown to black measures 40 ohms
>   Yellow to brown measures 80 ohms

[image: diagram]

**more photos here:**

https://photos.app.goo.gl/m1w3zwpYSZrEr93KA

[image: the motor]
I tried connecting black to ground and yellow/brown to main and it short circuited my house

Comment: Look up the wiring in google images for an induction motor and start/run cap https://www.google.com/search?q=induction+motor+and+start/run+cap&num=50&client=firefox-b-ab&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiexeaS_8bdAhUIrlkKHU_6DYgQ_AUIDigB&biw=1664&bih=819

Comment: Please draw a circuit diagram.

Comment: 120V60Hz or 230V50Hz?

Comment: Did you make notes to record where the wires were connected inside the drier? Is there a circuit diagram on the back of the drier? Did the motor work when the drier was taken out of service? When you say you connected yellow/brown to main do you mean you connected both at the same time? Did you connect black to earth or neutral?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientistn 230v/50hz

Comment: no diagram on drier, don't know if it worked. yellow and brown were not connected at the same time. I tried each one at a time and it shorted by house.

Comment: @winny added a diagram

Comment: Much better. Now, you have a DMM so no reason to resort to thinking. Measure if it’s ground or not! I suspect it isn’t and you have a proper two phase asynchronous induction motor.

Comment: @winny. Thanks.  As I am quite new to this can you explain the wiring? Btw what is dmm?

Comment: Digital multimeter. The one you used to measure resistance.

Comment: Please tell the brand and model of the dryer.

Answer (score 1):

That you can measure resistance to the black wire suggests that it isn't a ground connection (insulation resistance should be in the megohm range) plus the green/yellow wire visible in the background is likely the ground connection.
  [image: motor caps]

The cap-start arrangement  (b) is very common in driers, since the centrifugal switch can be used to keep the motor running after being started with a push-button, but that doesn't seem to be the case here, the centrifugal switch isn't visible, is's a generally fairly large black switch block at one end of the motor housings. There's also another board visible with a relay on it. That would suggest that you've got a PSC motor (a) which only needs two connections to it. The resistance measurements suggest that black is the common, and the brown would be the live feed, though I'm not sure why there would be an additional wire on the yellow then. Sometimes these manufacturers do really cheesy tricks like powering the controls off one winding on a motor.

Comment: there is no centrifugal switch in this motor.

Answer (score 1):

After going through a lot of googling and forums it seems this is motor is one the most simple ac motors out there. No centrifugal switch, just 2 coils. 
The black wire IS NOT GROUND!! to run the motor I attached the black wire to one of either brown or yellow wires.